# Difference between Action Job/Mailer's `deliver_now` and `deliver_later`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs, rails-activejob

The common pattern for interfacing with `ActiveJob` in Rails is to set up a Job with a `perform()` method that gets called asynchronously via `perform_now` or `perform_later`

In the special case of Mailers, you can directly call `deliver_now` or `deliver_later` since `ActiveJob` is well integrated with `ActionMailer`.

The [rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#action-mailer) has the following comments -

```
# If you want to send the email now use #deliver_now
UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliver_now
 
# If you want to send the email through Active Job use #deliver_later
UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliver_later
```

The wording makes it seem like `deliver_now` will *not* use `ActiveJob` to send the mail. Is that correct, and if so what's the true difference between `deliver_now` and `deliver_later`? Is one not asynchronous?

Similarly, does the same difference apply to `perform_now` and `perform_later` ?

Thanks!

Comment: To me it seems bad that ActionMailer and ActionJob mess with eachother like this. ActionJob should be agnostic to what the job is doing. ActionMailer should be able to be delayed by ActionJob without having to know that it is being delayed, just like any other object. To me this seems broken in Rails 3, 4, and 5.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As you say in your question, `deliver_now` does not use `ActiveJob`.

Basically, `deliver_later` is asynchronous. When you use this method, the email is not send at the moment, but rather is pushed in a job's queue. If the job is not running, the email will not be sent. `deliver_now` will send the email at the moment, no matter what is the job's state. [Here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later) you can see the documentation for `deliver` methods.

According to your second question, `perform_now` will process the job immediately without sending to the queue. `perform_later`, however, will add the job to the queue, and as soon the job's queue is free, will perform the job. [Here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Base.html) you can see the documentation for `perform` methods.

Comment: what if the browser connection is closed? Still deliver_later will be executed?

Comment: @gates `deliver_later` is managed on server side, so it does not matter if the browser connection is closed. Once a job is pushed to the queue, it will be sent (unless you kill the job process).

Comment: What is the behavior change if called from a script, executed via 'rails runner bin/send-lots-of-email.rb' I wonder?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what Daniel Batalla wrote, here's one more observation that I made: `deliver_later` seems to perform lazy evaluation, while `deliver_now` does not.

I have an ActiveRecord model with an additional attribute `reset_token` that is not stored in the database (this is from Michael Hartl's railstutorial.org; the model stores a hashed version of the token in the `reset_digest` column).

When executing `deliver_now`, accessing the `@model`'s `reset_token` attribute inside the mailer view yields the reset token as expected. However, when executing `deliver_later`, `@model.reset_token` is always `nil`. It appears as if `deliver_later` updates the model with database data, and because `reset_token` is an additional attribute that is not backed by the database, it will be `nil` at that point. (The code documentation is too deeply nested for me to be able to verify this in the source.)

Michael uses `deliver_now` in the tutorial. I don't know he does this to avoid lazy evaluation. But it took me a while to realize that I just had to change `deliver_later` to `deliver_now` to make my tests pass.

Comment: As the `deliver_later` is asynchronous, it would require to reload the object.  Like in any case of any asynchronous job. As it is required to take the new changes, if any, made to the job.

Comment: Thank you, @bovender.  I just had the same issue. In my Model there are a few methods to calculate total/gross prices and if I run mailer as follows `Mailer.payment_email(model, calculate_price).deliver_later`, `price` is always `nil`. Usage of `deliver_now` helps, but it ruins all benefits of async delivery. To overcome it I replaced `calculate_price` with `calculate_price.to_f`, it forces a method evaluation. In other cases it may be `to_i`, `to_s`, etc, depending on the data type returning by the method.

Comment: @ololobus How would one do deliver_later while keeping the current object state? In my case, I'm looking to access Active Record's dirty methods. Ex: record.changes. Deliver now works but deliver later has no changes.